# Query a specific record of a has_many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've run into this problem a few times, but I still don't have an elegant solution. I want to find all users by a specific association's value - "most recent", or "favorite"... something that narrows the association to 1 or so.

```rb
class User
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships do
    def favorite
      rank(:priority).first
    end
  end
end

class GroupMembership
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end

class Group
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships

  scope :in_state, ->(state) { where(state: state) }
end
```

So in this case, let's say a user can rank the groups that they're in. I want to find all users by querying their favorite group. They've set the priority of all the groups they belong to, which we won't worry about here.

Let's say I want to find all users whose favorite group is in a particular state, as a concrete example. This is my most recent attempt, and it doesn't work...

```rb
class User
  ...
  scope :favorite_group_in, lambda { |state|
    subquery = Group.rank(:priority).select(:id).limit(1).to_sql
    distinct.left_outer_joins(:groups)
            .where("groups.id = (#{subquery})")
            .merge(Group.in_state(state))
  }
end
```

I've tried creating a has_one, and trying to query through that, but that queries the whole table instead of being scoped to the has_one. I've tried window functions in postgres. I've tried subqueries in raw SQL. I can't be the only one that has this problem. What's the conventional solution to querying a subset of an association?

What **does work** is this... but I'm looking for a pure sql implementation for performance reasons.

```rb
class User
  ...
  scope :favorite_group_in, lambda { |state|
    ids = distinct.left_outer_joins(:groups).select { |u| u.groups.primary&.in_state?(state) }.pluck(:id)
    where(id: ids)
  }
end
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as it didn't pertain to your scope

Comment: Thanks for trying!

Answer (score -1):

I don't have my Rails environment on hand to try this out, but I believe you can do something like the following:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    scope :favorite_group_in, ->(state) { joins(:groups).where(groups: {state: state}) }
    ...
```

In terms of not-scopes, we are doing the following:

```rb
User.joins(:groups).where(groups: {state: state})
```

Comment: This is perfect for querying the entire relation. I’m wanting to check a specific record(s) of a relation.

Answer (score -2):

I am not very clear about your question but it sounds like something that can be resolved by Graph database. SQL Server 2017 comes with the Graph database. It's not the best Graph db tool but at least it is free.